# Implementing socket.io in mongoDB and Angular it is throwing errors Cannot GET /socket.io/

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, socket.io

I am developing an angular application which I need to use notifications for example.
I have a user which can add friends and then I can sent a friend request as in facebook and then the other user will be notificate in realtime for example You have one new notification, this user wants to be friends.

If anyone has better idea than `socket.io` I am free to listen and to learn

The problem it is that I get everytime **Cannot GET /socket.io/**

```
Request URL: http://localhost:4200/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NVvJf99
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:4200
```

I can show the list who sent me friend but I need everytime to reload page to see new requests.
I am using socket.io in both frameworks.
`Angular` I have installed with `npm` and the same in the mongoDB.
My server.js that is what I use for the requests and responses in frontend.

`Server.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const http = require('http');
const cors = require('cors');
const routes = require('./src/app/routes/routes');
const path = require('path');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');

const app = express();
const server = http.Server(app);
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://vip:admin@test-name-sn4qu.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
, {
useNewUrlParser: true,
useUnifiedTopology: true,
useFindAndModify: false
});

app.use(cors());
const io = socketIO(server);
app.set(io);

app.use(express.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));

app.use('/images', express.static(path.resolve(process.cwd(), '../images')));


app.use(routes);



mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: "Welcome to application." });
  });
 
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;




server.listen(PORT);
```

And then in the `friendController` I use something like this.

```
function createNewRequest(req, res, next) {
    const io = req.app.get('io');
    friendService.createNewRequest(req.body)
        .then(res.status(200).json({ message: 'Friend added successfully' }),
        io.emit('newTaskAdded'))
        .catch(err => next(err));
}
```

And then in the frontend I do have something like this.

And I am having an error which says
`Cannot find namespace 'SocketIOClient'. private socket:SocketIOClient.Socket;`

```
import * as io from "socket.io-client";
constructor() {
  this.socket = io();
}


ngOnInit(): void {
    this.LoadRequestingFriends();
    this.socket.on('newTaskAdded', () => {
      this.LoadRequestingFriends();
    })

  }
```

Comment: This `app.set(io);` should be more like this `app.set('io', io);` otherwise this `req.app.get('io');` will never work.

Comment: Also in the `createNewRequest` this `.then(res.status(200).json({ message: 'Friend added successfully' }), io.emit('newTaskAdded'))` should look more like this `.then(function(){ res.status(200).json({ message: 'Friend added successfully' }); io.emit('newTaskAdded'); })...`

Comment: @Molda I changed to `app.set('io', io);` and the `createNewRequest` as you said but still the same error.

Comment: Where do you see `Cannot GET /socket.io/` ?

Comment: In the frontend when I go to the route where I have the friends component and I use socket.io

Comment: What port is the app running at? What's the PORT value here `const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;`?

Comment: The value of it it is `5000`

Comment: So the url is not right `http://localhost:4200/socket.io/` the port is not 5000. Use this `this.socket = io("http://localhost:5000");`

Comment: @Molda So what is your opinion what i need to do ?

Comment: Well i assume your frontend is running on port 4200 and your socket server on port 5000. So you need to connect to it using `this.socket = io("http://localhost:5000");` or something like that

Comment: @Molda I have fixed it is trying to read from my server but it is saying.
{"code":5,"message":"Unsupported protocol version"} when i try to go to the link.
`http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NVvrdzE`
Cors Error

Comment: What do you mean `try got to the link ...` ? All you need is to tell socket.io client where to connect. you do that using this `this.socket = io("localhost:5000");` Read docs here https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-initialization/ you can also try the url with ws protocol like this `ws://localhost:5000` Also the error probably means that you use different versions of socket.io on client and server

Comment: @Molda I will edit my question and you will see the changesI have made.

Comment: The error `Cannot find namespace 'SocketIOClient'` has something to do with TypeScript. I'm not using typescript so can't help you with that.

Comment: @Molda I was able to fix it, the problem it was, typescript need to have different import and declaring the Socket.

Comment: @Molda can you add an answer so I can make it as accepted and maybe will help people in future ?